# Clearing data on New search Javascript

Tags: javascript, search, field

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am looking to clear out all the fields that are filled in from this script below when a second search is entered. This script fills in 25 boxes with shoe-sizes and prices after for looping through it all, the problem is if the next item searched does not have the same number of shoe sizes (which is often), the boxes are left with the previous data (ex. First shoe goes up to size 15, the next shoe search only goes up to size 12, so sizes 12.5-15 are left with the previous data because its not overwriting them).

```
  $('#searchForm').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let searchText = $('#search-box').val();
    $.ajax({
          url: "/",
          type: 'POST',
          data: { 
           input: searchText},
           success: function(res) {
              console.log(res);

              let product = res;

              document.getElementById("shoe").innerHTML = (product.stockx.shoeId);
              document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = (product.stockx.release);
              document.getElementById("sneakerid").style.backgroundImage = 'url('+(product.photo)+')';  
              document.getElementById("shoeOverlay").style.backgroundImage = 'url('+(product.photo)+')';  

              let size = product.stockx.price_size


              for( let i = 0; i < size.length; i += 1) {
                document.getElementById(i === 0 ? `shoesize` : `shoesize${i}`).innerHTML = (size[i].sizing), 
                document.getElementById(i === 0 ? `stockxprice` : `stockxprice${i}`).innerHTML = ('$' + size[i].pricing);

              } 


              for( let i = 0; i < product.sizes.length; i += 1) {
              document.getElementById(i === 0 ? `goatprice` : `goatprice${i}`).innerHTML = ('$' + product.sizes[i][1]*.01);
              if (product.sizes[i][1]*.01 > size[i].pricing) document.getElementById(i === 0 ? `goatprice` : `goatprice${i}`).style.color = "#00ffb3";
              else if (product.sizes[i][1]*.01 < size[i].pricing) document.getElementById(i === 0 ? `stockxprice` : `stockxprice${i}`).style.color = "#00ffb3";

                }


            }}
      )})
})
```

HTML snippet

```
       <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="innerbox">
                <div id="shoesize" ></div>
                  <div class="prices">
                    <div id="stockxprice"></div>
                    <div id="goatprice"></div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="logocontainer">
                      <div class="stockxlogo"> <img src="img/stockxlogo.svg" ></div> 
                       <div class="goatlogo"><img src="img/goatlogo.svg" height="30px" width="30px"></div> 

                  </div>



<form id="searchForm">
                   <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="search-box">
                   <div class="searchlogo"> <img src="img/searchlogo.svg" height="15px" width="15px" href="#"></div>
                  </form>

                </div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plWLo.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements **are inside a `form`**, you can use the `form.reset()` method.

---

HTMLFormElement.reset():

> The HTMLFormElement.reset() method restores a form element's default values. This method does the same thing as clicking the form's reset button.

you can read more here: [HTMLFormElement.reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

---

Run and test:

```js
function resetForm() {
  let form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  form.reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
</form>

<input type="button" value="reset" onclick="resetForm()" />
```

---

**EDIT:** If the elements **are not inside a `form`**:

If your elements are not inside a form, you can then give them all a common class name to help you iterate through them.

Run and test:

```js
function resetElems() {
  $(".resetable").html("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="shoesize" class="resetable">15</div>
<div class="prices">
  <div id="stockxprice" class="resetable">13</div>
  <div id="goatprice" class="resetable">14</div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="click to reset" onclick="resetElems()" />
```

---

**EDIT 2:** To only reset on the second search and after:

If you wish to only perform the reset after the first search you can declare a global variable to keep count of the searches (increment it on every search) and then do something like this:

```
var count = 0; // this variable is global; it's not inside any function

$('#searchForm').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let searchText = $('#search-box').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
            input: searchText
        },
        success: function(res) {
            if(count > 0) {  // only reset if it's not the first search
                $(".resetable").html("");
            }

            count++;         // increment the count

            // other code ...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @ivan86 all the data is held in table and filled when just pressing enter key on search-bar, i've uploaded a snippet of the HTML so you can see what I mean, the problem is I need it clear on the second time I search, not the first

Comment: @N3VO I don't see the snippet of HTML :/

Comment: @N3VO Eh, well that changes things then :)

Comment: @N3VO Check my edit, I believe this is what you were after.

Comment: it does work, but there is an issue, its deleting everything after I hit enter on the first search, is there a way to have it just run only after the second+ search?

Comment: @N3VO Can you put the `$(".resetable").html("");` as the first instruction right here `success: function(res) { $(".resetable").html("");`

Comment: @N3VO If you put the reset method like in the above comment, your elements will be erased every time before anything is written inside them

Comment: @N3VO but yes, there is also a way to only do that on the second+ search... You can declare a global variable `var count = 0;` and then increment it every time you do a search. Then it would be easy to do a quick `if (count > 0) { $(".resetable").html(""); }`. Let me know if you need help with this

Comment: that first  part works fine, but yes any info on the var count would be great, you have been very helpful thank you, I am always trying to learn more!

Comment: @N3VO Ok, I'll edit to show a small example of the count part

Comment: @N3VO take a look at my second edit at the bottom. It shows you how to do the count part.

Comment: perfect thank you! that makes a lot of sense, one more thing if you have the time, is there a way to clear the colors out as well? I've been trying to no avail, if you look at the script I have an if statement that compares two numbers and whichever one is > it turns green, problem is now I notice that it does not reset the green color on the new search, I tried your method but with jquery with the .style.color which is attached to the CSS property, but its not changing it back

Comment: @N3VO in jQuery you would use the `.css()` method like this: `$('#someID').css("color","#00ffb3");`, while in plain javascript you would use `document.getElementById("someID").style.color = "#00ffb3";`. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: yes! $(".resetable").css("color","#ffffff"); using this works great, realized this already being called anyways for resetting the data so I could also use it to reset the color. thank you again! really appreciate your help.